# Google Home - Is reporting state mandatory?

Tags: integration, actions-on-google, google-home

I'm trying to validate our integration with Google Home, and as it turns out, the smart home test suite expects reporting state to be implemented. 
AFAIK, this is not necessary, but evidently, at least for this test suit, it is. I'm always reporting "willReportState" as false, which should be fine, and the test suite skips most devices because of this, but for some reason, it still expects thermostats to report state.

Does this mean that the only way to get our integration approved and listed is if we implement a reporting state?

Here's an example of the sync for a thermostat:

```
{ 
   "id":"112299",
   "type":"action.devices.types.THERMOSTAT",
   "traits":[ 
      "action.devices.traits.OnOff",
      "action.devices.traits.TemperatureSetting"
   ],
   "name":{ 
      "name":"Calefacción Agus"
   },
   "willReportState":false,
   "attributes":{ 
      "availableThermostatModes":"off,heat",
      "thermostatTemperatureUnit":"C"
   },
   "roomHint":"Cuarto Agus",
   "deviceInfo":{ 
      "model":"HPA-4412",
      "swVersion":""
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Report state](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/report-state) is a requirement for submitting your smart home action unless your device traits use the `commandOnly<TraitName>` attribute and do not know the state.

For example, some devices like an IR blaster may only know how to send commands and don't know the state, so it would use [OnOff](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/onoff) with the `commandOnlyOnOff` attribute.

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you, I'll give that a try, but it's not really what I want, because I thought using attribute "willReportState" set to false should be enough. Interestingly, the suite seems to skip all devices that have the attribute "willReportState" set to false, with the exception of Thermostats. For those, it sends a voice command during the test (which is executed correctly), and then apparently waits, I suppose it's waiting for the state to change. I've now added the sync of a thermostat, as an example.

Comment: You can set the attribute to false technically, but the submission policy is to implement it.